# Gerrit Trigger Connection fails

Tags: ssh, jenkins, triggers, connection, gerrit

I'm trying to get the Gerrit Trigger Plugin of Jenkins working, but it continues to throw Exceptions when I'm trying to test the connection. I don't even get a useful Error-Message. The Servers Error Log is empty too.

Since there is some SSH-Stuff in the Stacktrace I added my SSH Keyfile. Maybe that can help to address the Issue.

Stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:778)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:74)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.util.SimpleASNReader.getByte(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.util.SimpleASNReader.assertByte(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.openssh.RSAKeyInfo.getRSAKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.openssh.OpenSSHPrivateKeyFormat.decryptKeyblob(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.publickey.SshPrivateKeyFile.toPrivateKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.gerritevents.ssh.SshUtil.checkPassPhrase(SshUtil.java:75)
    at com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.GerritServer$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(GerritServer.java:519)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor278.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    ... 63 more
```

SSH Private Key File:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Comment: qp10009
Private-Lines: 14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-MAC: 0a0c4ca43a3e06d9e057d9c550931a7475ed6fc6
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect manually from the jenkins server first?

Comment: You should stop posting private keys ;-)

Comment: no worries, this key is just for testing purposes and wont be used afterwards... :-)

Comment: Does this post can help you ? http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38761745/2394026

Answer (score 0):

You can try following these instructions on how to setup the ssh key form jenkins under windows: http://blog.bruin.sg/2013/04/setup-ssh-key-pair-for-jenkins-under-windows/

Comment: when i start the bash.exe i got with my Git Installation, it tells me that the ssh-keygen command is not found.

Comment: It should be in your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` folder