# Jenkins Failed to connect to gerrit repository (Windows installation)

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I looked around Stackoverflow and google a lot but I am not able to solve my issue.

**My aim** : I want to set up Jenkins to use git SCM to clone a repository host by gerrit

**My Jenkins config**

- Jenkins version 2.7.1 running on windows as a service
- Git plugin version 2.5.3
- Multiple SCM plugin version 0.6
- Gerrit Trigger plugin version 2.21.1

**The issue**

The *URL* is configured as `IHM@IP:/path/to/gerrit/git/IHM.git`. `IHM`is the user which launched Jenkins on a windows server. `IP`is the adress of the red hat server hosting gerrit.

Credentials are set to use user `IHM` with the ssh key enter directly. The key has been generated using PuttyGen on the windows server. I didn't set up the ssh key on a config on windows server. *Do I have to do it ?*

I have the following error, but I am able to run the command prompt on the windows server with user `IHM` (it ask me the password but then it works).

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program
> Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h
> IHM@IP:/path/to/gerrit/git/IHM.git HEAD" returned status code -1:
>
> stdout:
>
> stderr:

Comment: Could you try with a key generated with openssh instead of Putty? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38322325/6309) And copy your public key (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885920/using-ssh-keygen-not-able-to-connect-to-server-on-windows-10-git/38890127#38890127) as a credential in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I figure out with another way but your answer let me ask new questions

Comment: Well done! +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to set up the repository by setting up again from scratch.

Here is my config, for example to others:

- **user** = The user I used to connect to gerrit
- **IP** = Gerrit serveur IP adress
- **Repository URL**   = ssh://**user**@**IP**:29418/IHM.git > Do not put the entire path
- **Credentials** are used with the private key generated with Putty and which public key is configure to gerrit
- **Refspec** = refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
- **Branches to build** = $GERRIT_REFSPEC