# Using SSH Keygen not able to connect to server on Windows 10 GIT

Tags: windows, git, ssh, private-key

I'm following below tutorial.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

It's generated file on Windows 10 `C:\Users\<user name>\.ssh`

I'm using GIT to generate files.

```
 ~/Desktop
$ PermitRootLogin without-password
bash: PermitRootLogin: command not found

$ ssh a@b.com
a@b.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I have generated `.ppk` file using `puttygen.exe`.
Still not able to connect to server.

By doing `ssh -Tv a@b.com`

It will give below response

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to a@b.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to a@b.com:22 as 'XUser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:WrjAO7ldoJ3vjYENd6v7JvxXkbquvvom16RYGKeRO70
debug1: Host 'a@b.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
XUser@a@b.com's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
XUser@a@b.com's password:
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do have

- your public key: `C:\Users\<user name>\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`
- your private key: `C:\Users\<user name>\.ssh\id_rsa`

Do copy your public key (see "[How To Use SSH Keys with DigitalOcean Droplets](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-digitalocean-droplets)")

[image: https://assets.digitalocean.com/articles/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-digitalocean-droplets/key_added.png]

Comment: @MikeSmith So you do have id_rsa and id_rsa.pub?

Comment: @MikeSmith Are you sure you have copied your key without any "newlines" in it (it should be one continuous line)

Comment: Yes i have id_rsa & id_rsa.pub.  Yes copied w/o any "newlines" Thanks

Comment: @MikeSmith then are you sure of the user 'a' that you are connecting with, when you do a `ssh a@b.com`?

Comment: @MikeSmith If you are, then try a `ssh -Tv a@b.com` to see if there is any clue.

Comment: i added in question

Comment: @MikeSmith You pubilc key is found and proposed... but rejected. I suppose `a` is not the right user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120674/discussion-between-mike-smith-and-vonc).

Comment: Not sure about this. What will be the steps to achieve/solve?

Comment: @MikeSmith Sorry for the terse comment earlier, I was a bit in a rush. Let me illustrate: If you try to connect to GitHub.com through ssh for instance, you would not use your GitHub login (`ssh mylogin@github.com`): that would *never* work. You would need to use git: `ssh git@github.com`. Maybe this is similar for DigitalOcean.

Comment: @MikeSmith For instance, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-your-droplet-with-ssh illustrates ssh access using root, as the remote user to log in as. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-freebsd-server uses the user account name `freebsd`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I'm using another server for this. Will check & update you