# Can't connect to Gerrit ssh shell after installation

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have installed Gerrit and added my SSH key to settings. Port 29418 is opening. But now I can't login with SSH. I created jenkins user for Gerrit, neither could I correctly configure the server connection in Jenkins Gerrit Trigger.

Could you help me to check it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Add "-vvv" to the "ssh" command to see what happens.

Comment: Does this post can help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38761745/2394026

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira I have tried and post the output in the body. It seems like a ssh issue.

Comment: @Flows I think that solution doesn't match my issue. I have just installed Gerrit and Jenkins, the repository is not created. Neither can I connect to Gerrit in my local computer nor in Jenkins.

Comment: @LearnToDeath yes, it seems like a ssh issue. You could try to regenerate the key: ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "<comment>"

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira But the ssh key in my local computer works well with other applications, like github and another gerrit, I think the ssh issue may happen in gerrit server. How can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

**Check all steps:**

1. Generate your ssh key on your host:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

2. Add public key in Gerrit in: **user -> settings -> ssh public key -> add key**
3. Check your connection using this command: **ssh user@host -p 29418**
4. If you see **Welcome to Gerrit Code Review** that you have good add yours ssh key

Comment: My local ssh key is already exist and it works well with other applications like github and another gerrit. I think this issue may happen in gerrit server. How can I check it?

Comment: By the way, I am really confused by how it works. I mean, I have an account in gerrit, but this account is not exist in OS level(I create it by using htpasswd command), I know how ssh works when two real OS accounts in two hosts are communicating, they exchange publish ssh keys; but how it works when using port 29418, and in gerrit server side no real OS user exist? Do you have good place introducing these knowledge?

Comment: Maby check this e-book "Learning Gerrit Code Review [eBook]" there is a lot of information ;)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Now I have solved it by installing gerrit a second time with a different user, not root. Though I still don't understand why it doesn't work before. I will read that book for more details.